# Web2Py SQLFORM.Grid

Tags: python, mysql, web2py

I'm just starting out on the web2py and really can't get pass the SQLFORM.grid part.
My data is in mySQL db and i'm trying to call a query for it.

I defined the table but without the id field because i called it "itemNumber" and used that as my id field.

```
db.define_table('items', 
   Field('itemNumber', 'integer'),
   Field('title', 'string'),
   Field('price', 'integer'),
   Field('numSold', 'integer'))
```

in my default.py

```
def display_form():
    db.items.id.readable = False
    query = (db.items.numSold)
    fields = (db.items.price, db.items.numSold, db.items.title)
    headers = {'items.price': 'Price', 'items.numSold': '# Sold', 'items.title': 'Title'}
    default_sort_order = [db.items.numSold]

    form = SQLFORM.grid(query=query, fields=fields, headers=headers, orderby=default_sort_order, create=False, deletable=False, editable=False, maxtextlength=64, 
                        paginate = 25)
    return dict(form=form)
```

The error provided on the html page:
Query Not Supported: (1054, u"Unknown column 'items.id' in 'field list'")
No records found

I thought i read that SQLFORM.grid automatically calls for ".id"  But what if the unique key, in my case, is named itemNumber instead of id?

How do i turn that off?

Thanks so much,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table definition should start as follows:

```
db.define_table('items', 
   Field('itemNumber', 'id'),
```

When you specify the field type as "id", web2py will treat that field as the auto-incrementing integer primary key and will not create a separate field named "id".

Comment: Awesome Anthony!! Thank you so much. that totally did the trick!